# The save() method in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am doing some self-learning about cakePHP 1.26.
I got a table which has two fields {topic, username}

I got a simple HMTL form like this:

```
<input type=text name="data[testing][topic]" id="data[testing][topic]"/>
```

The data from this input field was passed to the specific controller with this code:

```
$who=$this->Session->read('user.name'); // username retrieved successfully
$this->Testing->save($this->data);
```

When I checked the database, I could only see the data from the Input text field, but
the username field is empty.
How do I alter the code in the controller so that the username retrieved from the session can be saved into the database?

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$who=$this->Session->read('User.id');
$this->data['Testing']['user_id'] = $who; // set the data
$this->Testing->save($this->data);
```

Answer (score 1):

$hello=$this->Session->read('Test.name');

$this->data['Testing']['test_name'] = $hello;

$this->Testing->save($this->data);